# X server on NVIDIA card with no screen

Tags: xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a rather unique situation where I have a server with an NVIDIA graphics card installed that we need to have X server running on however the server lives on a rack with no monitor. The reason for having X running is for rendering operations with a program using Qt. There are huge benefits in efficiency by using GPU rendering rather than CPU. Whenever i `startx`, X fails to start because no screen is attached. What is the best method for starting x with a fake monitor? OS is RHEL 6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I don't know if this is *'the best way'*, but it's how I do it.**

Use nvidia-settings GUI to make a edid file for a screen

***Then in the terminal of your choice paste or write:***

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --allow-empty-initial-configuration \
--use-display-device="DFP-0" --connected-monitor="DFP-0" \
--custom-edid="DFP-0:/home/$USER/edid.txt" 

sudo reboot
```

To add GPU(s) and screens to xorg.conf.

If you want to be able to overclock and control the fan(s) as well, add '--cool-bits=12' (or whatever NVIDIA documentation says is applicable for your driver) to the 'nvidia-xconfig' line on the top.

If you don't have a way of making a edid file, or can't find one here is the one I use:

```
00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 1e 6d f5 56 71 ca 04 00 05 14 01 03 80 35 1e 78 0a ae c5 a2 57 4a 9c 25 12 50 54 21 08 00 b3 00 81 80 81 40 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 1a 36 80 a0 70 38 1f 40 30 20 35 00 13 2b 21 00 00 1a 02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40 58 2c 45 00 13 2b 21 00 00 1e 00 00 00 fd 00 38 3d 1e 53 0f 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 57 32 34 35 33 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 01 3d 02 03 21 f1 4e 90 04 03 01 14 12 05 1f 10 13 00 00 00 00 23 09 07 07 83 01 00 00 65 03 0c 00 10 00 02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40 58 2c 45 00 13 2b 21 00 00 1e 01 1d 80 18 71 1c 16 20 58 2c 25 00 13 2b 21 00 00 9e 01 1d 00 72 51 d0 1e 20 6e 28 55 00 13 2b 21 00 00 1e 8c 0a d0 8a 20 e0 2d 10 10 3e 96 00 13 2b 21 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 26
```

Save to edid.txt in home directory of your user, or change location in configuration line.

***If you enable overclocking and want to use a screen on your main GPU:***

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Remove lines:

```
Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP-0"
Option         "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/home/nv/edid.bin"
Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP-0"
```

from the 'Section "Screen"' that has your GPUID with screen attached and assigned to it.

**Overclocking!**

***Power limit:***

```
sudo nvidia-smi -i GPUID -pl WATTLIMIT
```

***Core clock:***

```
nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [gpu:GPUID]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=16
```

:0 is the X screen assigned to GPU, GPUID is as guessed the number of the GPU (counting from 0).

16 == offset.

Use negative numbers to underclock.

***Memory clock:***

```
nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [gpu:GPUID]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=1200
```

If you are used to Afterburner etc. you have to double the offset values in Linux(circa).

I always get more juice out of my cards on a Linux system(*for my use*)

***Enable and control fan(s) manually:***

```
nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [gpu:GPUID]/GPUFanControlState=1
nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [fan:GPUID]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=85
```

Set GPUFanControlState back to 0 to disable manual control.

GPUTargetFanSpeed takes an integer from 0 to 100 as input.

***Check temperature, power usage etc.:***

```
nvidia-smi
```

**If process gets locked in a low power state by GPU, the only workaround I found was to create an application profile, there was/is no way to control P state. At least on consumer cards.**

***Here is the process:***

```
cd ~/.nv
cat > nvidia-application-profiles-rc
```

Paste this template:

```
{
"rules": [
    {
        "pattern": {
            "feature": "procname",
            "matches": "NameOfRunningProcessThatWantsMorePriority"
        },
        "profile": "ProfileNameWhatever"
    }
],
"profiles": [
    {
        "name": "ProfileNameWhatever",
        "settings": []
    }
]
}
```

Press enter then CTRL + C before you edit with whatever suits your taste.

Start your process and type nvidia-smi to get the process name to use in the application profile.

Alternatively, if you have access to the GUI you can make the application profile there.

***To keep custom power limit(s) across reboots "Persistence Mode" has to be enabled.***

***To enable it on all GPU's:***

```
sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1
```

***To enable it on a specific GPU:***

```
sudo nvidia-smi -i GPUID -pm 1
```

Persistence Mode will help with speed if running headless and running several small processes after each other, as GPU does not go to sleep between jobs, this will reduce time to process many small tasks a good deal!
**Will raise idle consumption when activated!**

**ADDITIONAL INFO WHEN USING lightdm !!**
**Regular methods produce problems on newer Ubuntu systems**

**Like everything else actually configuring stuff, use root account or sudo**

***Fan control:***

```
# DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [gpu:GPUID]/GPUFanControlState=1
# DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [fan:GPUID]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=70
```

***Over/underclock:***

```
# DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [gpu:GPUID]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=64
# DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [gpu:GPUID]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=1100
```

**# == root, or sudo**

*If problems arise when everything is running(or not), NVIDIA has posted some nice queries for troubleshooting:*

[**Useful nvidia-smi Queries**](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3751/~/useful-nvidia-smi-queries)

**Other;**

**[ArchLinux Wiki's Tips and Tricks on NVIDIA](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks)**

**[xconfig appendix NVIDIA driver 384.98](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/384.98/README/xconfigoptions.html)**

**Just change driver version in URL to your driver version, and you'll be on the right track.**

Comment: Glad to help! Took me a while to figure this stuff out, so if I can save someone else the trouble.. :) You may need some extra packages if you don't have any desktop environment installed, let me know if you get any problems.

Comment: And if the solution helped you, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Of course. Will do, just trying it now

Comment: Thanks Anders for going into so much detail! Very helpful to me, and hopefully others

Comment: Currently facing some issues @anders Could you maybe give a look? https://superuser.com/questions/1779799/xrandr-cant-open-display-trying-to-add-fake-display