# Ubuntu CUDA driver only working when using graphics card for display

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, cuda

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have a Nvidia Geforce GTX 970.

I have successfully installed both the graphics card driver and the CUDA toolkit and have been using it with `Ethminer` to mine `Ethereum`.

When I am actually using the graphics card as my display hardware as well, i.e. my monitor is plugged into my graphics card, this works without a problem.

I would however prefer to use my graphics card for GPU processing only and thus plug my monitor into my motherboard graphics card.

When I do this, however, it seems like I am unable to use my Geforce card.

Without having changed any drivers/setting and trying to run `Ethminer` I get the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  No CUDA driver found
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am sure it must be possible to use a GPU without it being plugged in? Any advice?

Comment: Please check out my answer to another user about the same subject, I think you will find all the details you need. Then please upvote if it works out for you. Thanks! https://superuser.com/questions/1278256/x-server-on-nvidia-card-with-no-screen   Wow.. Just saw this was super old.